# Unit test karma angular-jwt

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, jwt

I try to test this with Karma/Jasmine :

```
.config(function Config($httpProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider, jwtOptionsProvider, APP_CONFIG) {
  jwtOptionsProvider.config({ 
    whiteListedDomains: ['172.19.11.155'],
    unauthenticatedRedirectPath: '/auth'
  });

  jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = function() {
    var token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    return token;
  };

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
})
```

Someone know how to test this ?

```
beforeEach(module('app', function (_$httpProvider_, jwtInterceptorProvider) {
    $httpProvider = _$httpProvider_;

    jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = function() {
       return 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1..';
    }
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
}));
```

When i run my test, error is return :

> Unknown provider: Error: JWT must have 3 parts

I don't understand how i can inject token in all request with interceptor in unit test.

Comment: Why would you need your token (or any token) in a unit test? Any HTTP requests should be going through `$httpBackend` from `ng-mock`

Comment: I miss $httpBackend ! thanks